# Matching quote wrapped strings in javascript with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for javascript for matching

```
"{any group of chars}" <-- where that last " is not preceeded by a \
```

examples:

```
... foo "bar" ...  => "bar"
... foo"bar\"" ... => "bar\""
... foo "bar" ...  goo"o"ooogle "t\"e\"st"[] => ["bar", "o", "t\"e\"st"]
```

The actual strings will be longer and may contain multiple matches that could also include white space or regex special chars.

I have started by trying to break down the syntax but not being strong with regex myself I got stuck pretty fast but i did get as far as matching everything except for the case where the match contains \" (i think) ...

https://regex101.com/r/sj4HXw/1

UPDATE:

More about my situation ...

This regex is to be used to "syntax highlight" strings in code blocks embedded in my blog posts so a real world example might look something like this ...

```
<pre id="test" class="code" data-code="csharp">
   if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogSql"] == "true")
</pre>
```

And I am using the following javascript to achieve the highlight ..

```
var result = $("#test").text().replace(/"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"/g, "<span class=\"string\">$1</span>");
$("#test").html(result);
```

For some reason even when the suggested answers (so far at least) are used in this context i'm getting odd results.

This works but puts the value $1 instead of the actual match for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simple scenario (as in OP)

The most efficient regex (that is written in accordance with the [*unroll-the-loop* principle](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop)) you may use here is

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KxVhDk/1)

**Details**:

- `"` - match the first `"`
- `[^"\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `"` and `\`
- `(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*` - zer or more occurrences of:

  - `\\[\s\S]` - any char (`[\s\S]`) with a `\` in front
  - `[^"\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `"` and `\`
- `"` - a closing `"`.

Usage:

```js
// MATCHING
var rx = /"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"/g;
var s = '    ... foo "bar" ...  goo"o"ooogle "t\\"e\\"st"[]';
var res = s.match(rx);
console.log(res);

// REPLACING
console.log(s.replace(rx, '<span>$&</span>'));
```

## More advanced scenario

If there is an escaped `"` before a valid match or there are `\`s before a `"`, the approach above won't work. You will need to match those `\`s and capture the substring you need.

```
/(?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*")/g
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                             ^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KxVhDk/2).

Usage:

```js
// MATCHING
var rx = /(?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*")/g;
var s = '    ... \\"foo "bar" ...  goo"o"ooogle "t\\"e\\"st"[]';
var m, res=[];
while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);

// REPLACING
console.log(s.replace(/((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*")/g, '$1<span>$2</span>'));
```

The main pattern is wrapped with capturing parentheses, and this is added at the start:

- `(?:^|[^\\])` - either start of string or any char but `\`
- `(?:\\{2})*` - 0+ occurrences of a double backslash.

Comment: Interesting, given how I intend to use this I don't think the more complex scenario applies here, for reason though I couldn't get your simpler solution to work.

Comment: I updated the question because I figured you might ask that ... it's pretty relevant info :) see my update :)

Comment: You are trying to replace the matches. Use `.replace(/first regex/g, '<span>$&</span>')`. To use the more complex one, you will ned to wrap the starting part with another capturing group and use two backreferences in the replacement pattern. Sorry, I'm on the mobile now and can't provide a demo.

Comment: cracked it ... this is the final solution ... input.replace(/("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*")/g, "<span class=\"string\">$1</span>");

Comment: notice how I took your simple solution and just added an extra set of () round it as without them it outputs $1 instead of the match

Comment: Your link doesn't explain when it's necessary to use unroll-the-loop. But I don't believe this is one of those times.

Comment: @DavidKnipe: I have not said it is necessary, it is just best practice in the regex world: linearly matching patterns are just more efficient. I explained why the `"(\\.|[^"])*"` pattern is slower than mine in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831523/matching-quote-wrapped-strings-in-javascript-with-regex/43831590?noredirect=1#comment74705701_43831590).

Comment: And I'm saying in this case it does match in linear time even without unroll-the-loop.

Comment: @War: I added *replacing* code to both snippets to show how you could use **backreferences** to your advantage.

Answer (score 4):

Prioritize the escaped characters first:

```
"(\\.|[^"])*"
```

https://regex101.com/r/sj4HXw/2

Comment: Simple answer :)

Comment: doesn't quite work though in place ... might be something weird in my js though

Comment: When you work for the raw string input, you will need to double the backslashes: `'foo "bar" ...  goo"o"ooogle "t\\"e\\"st"[]'`

Comment: The `"(\\.|[^"])*"` regex won't work in a [more complex sceanrio](https://regex101.com/r/ChEmRH/1) and when a newline or a carriage return is escaped. Besides, it will cause unnecessary backtracking due to the alternation inside the pattern.

Comment: In testing it seems that this solution appears to take only the last char from the matched set inside the quotes ... odd behaviour because it clearly looks like it matches on regex101

Comment: @Wiktor Your regex produces exactly the same matches for that example. I don't see it as a problem though; it's a bad example because it starts with a `\"`. Can you give an example where it takes longer than linear time? I don't believe it can. The newlines problem is easily fixed: replace `.` with `[\s\S]`, as in your answer. Oh, and don't forget to add `\\ ` to the character class, otherwise it matches (for example) `"\"`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe: Yes, my first regex produces the same results. A bad example? No idea, but we should account for any kind of user input. I do not mean to say this regex is slow, just alternation in this case will be slowing matching down as `[^"]` matches ``\`` (and that means both branches may match at the same position in the string, and then it will cause unnecessary backtracking, which usually slows regex matching). Yes, `[\s\S]` or `[^]` will match *any* char.

Comment: Actually I'd only looked at the first of Wiktor's solutions. The other version does indeed give a better result in the regex101 example. But once you get into the question of what to do with malformed strings like that, I'm not sure whether it's even clear what we want in all cases. For example, would we want to ignore a `"` at the start if it means each string literal is confined to just one line?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
"(\\[\s\S]|[^"\\])*"
```

It's a mixture of the other answers from Wiktor and Taufik.